# Matching a value in R

Tags: r, summary

If I have two vectors:

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
B<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
```

and each value in B corresponds to the value in A. If I for example run:

```
summary(B)
```

this will give me summary statistics for the values in B. My question is how do I figure out which values in A those summary stats correspond to?

Comment: Perhaps `match(summary(B), B)`  The question is not very clear

Comment: Can you say more about what you want and how the variables are related?

Comment: I just had a data set where I had one column of country names, and another of GDP values, I did the summary stats on the GDP values but then wanted to know which countries those summary stats applied to, for example, which country had the highest gdp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first quintile stat of `B`can be accessed like this:

```
summary(B)[2]
1st Qu. 
     30
```

Then `B==summary(B)[2]` will give you a boolean vector you can apply to `A` to extract its corresponding value like this:

```
A[B==summary(B)[2]]
[1] 3
```

So in this cas the value 30 in `B` corresponds to 3 in `A`. Note that in a more realistic setting, you might find different values in `B` that match the summary statistics (or none in the case of the mean).

Comment: In my actual data set I have 214 observations, I get the following error when I try out this code:

> gdp$Country.Name[log(gdp$Y2013)==17.46]
 [1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[18] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[35] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
214 Levels: Afghanistan Albania Algeria American Samoa Andorra Angola ... Zimbabwe
$$

Not really sure what this means?

Comment: It looks like your country variable is a factor. Does it help if you convert it to character? `as.character(gdp$Country.Name)`.

Comment: still just gives me a string of NAs

Comment: Does it happen for all the different summary statistics? Because it could happen that no value corresponds to the precise stat.

Comment: that stat is the minimum so I thought it should definitely have a corresponding country

Comment: You probably have NA's in your GDP variable. If it doesn't find a match, this code returns either `factor(0)`or `character(0)`.

Comment: any suggestions as to how to get around this with the code you recommended?

Comment: I was able to replicate your problem and the solution was to add the  argument `digits=6` to `summary` to avoid rounding errors. Also, remove the `NA`s with complete.cases for example.

Comment: @dimebucker91, if you want the country(ies) with the minimum value of variable `Y2013`, you can just do: `gdp$Country.Name[gdp$Y2013==min(gdp$Y2013,na.rm=T)]`